# VBA: Pass typename to function as parameter (Inventor iLogic)

Tags: vba, types

I want to create function with type check.

```
function MyFunc(ByVal Obj As Object, Typ As Type) As Boolean
  ...
  If TypeOf Obj Is typ Then
  ...
End Function
```

For standard Types is not problem to compare string returned by [`TypeName(Obj)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function) as described here: [2010 VBA - Pass Type as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007364/2010-vba-pass-type-as-parameter)

But it's tricky in iLogic. There is main Type [`Document`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-CF60F6F3-8074-4719-B8E0-5E482E5AF783) and derived "sub-types" [`AssemblyDocument`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-43BDB2E7-2222-420E-926D-FA46E00FB511), [`DrawingDocument`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-902B2746-25C9-41A6-953E-C22C28C880AE)...

Every of these sub-types is `Document` type as well. For my purpose I'm not interested what Document sub-type it is. I need to check only main `Document` type.

Better to explain on some code:

```
Dim Obj As Document
Obj = ThisDoc.Document

Logger.Debug(TypeName(Obj)) ' <-- Returns: AssemblyDocument
Logger.Debug(TypeOf Obj Is Document) ' <-- Returns: True

Logger.Debug(TypeName(ThisDoc.Document)) ' <-- Returns: AssemblyDocument
Logger.Debug(TypeOf ThisDoc.Document Is Document) ' <-- Returns: True
```

So, is there way how to pass a Type to function, or is only way to get list of possible sub-types and compare them item by item with string result of `TypeName(Obj)`?

Comment: Do the document subtypes have a parent method?  e.g.  TypName(ThisDocument.Document.Parent)

Comment: `Document.Parent` returns `Application object`. I don't know why, but today `TypeName(Obj)` returns `_DocumentClass` for every Document-like type. Can't reproduce behavior described in the Question anymore. Wierd (same code).